# Is it possible to build a Google Map showing nothing but overlays?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an odd question: would it be possible to build a page containing a Google Map that doesn't actually display the map, i.e. the only things shown in the  are the overlays and markers you've created?

I'm looking for a way to build a map that appears empty except for the content that I overlay on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you add markers and overlays, they won't show up until you add them to the map. The map can show different features, but you can't just have a blank div with markers and overlays. Why do you see this need?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "styled map" features and create a blank map like:

```
var stylez05 = [ { 
  featureType: "all", 
  elementType: "all", 
  stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
}];
```

http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple.html is an example of how to apply styles to a map.